# Кросс-отчеты в Fastreport 5.0

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, fastreport

Работаю на данный момент на Delphi XE7, там по умолчанию уже устанавливается FastReport 5.0. Хотел бы знать, как там можно создавать кросс-отчеты там? На англоязычном форуме пишут, что там нельзя такое создавать. Потому спрашиваю, какая альтернатива представлена тогда в новом генераторе отчетов?

Comment: Странно, ведь в 4 версии кросс-отчеты были. Не стали же их специально убирать?

Answer (score 2):

В FR 5-ой версии компонента crossobject не поставляется в комплекте с RAD Studio. 
Как альтернатива - приобретать отдельно в комплектации Standart или выше
Или же сразу форматировать данные перед отправкой их в репорт

Comment: То есть в составе RAD Studio, забесплатно, идёт усеченный FastReport без кроссов?